# SonarQube Community 10.2.1 and sonarqube-community-branch-plugin 1.14.0 issue

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, compatibility

Hi everyone I am trying to use the  sonarqube-community-branch-plugin 1.14.0 plugin with sonarqube Community 10.2.1. I followed the installation steps in the documentation here :
[here](https://github.com/mc1arke/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin)

Butwhen i try to run it I got the following error :

```
\temp\sq-process8801222574988639052properties
19:28:19.432 [main] INFO com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.CommunityBranchAgent -- Loading agent
19:28:19.439 [main] DEBUG com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.CommunityBranchAgent -- Transforming class org.sonar.server.almsettings.MultipleAlmFeature
19:28:19.458 [main] ERROR com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.CommunityBranchAgent -- Could not transform class org.sonar.server.almsettings.MultipleAlmFeature, will use default class definition
javassist.NotFoundException: isEnabled(..) is not found in org.sonar.server.almsettings.MultipleAlmFeature
        at javassist.CtClassType.getDeclaredMethod(CtClassType.java:1356)
        at com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.CommunityBranchAgent.lambda$redefineIsEnabledFlag$2(CommunityBranchAgent.java:107)
        at com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.CommunityBranchAgent$1.transform(CommunityBranchAgent.java:81)
        at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:244)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:541)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
        at com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.CommunityBranchAgent.redefineEdition(CommunityBranchAgent.java:94)
        at com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.CommunityBranchAgent.premain(CommunityBranchAgent.java:57)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:491)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:503)
19:28:19.463 [main] DEBUG com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.CommunityBranchAgent -- Transforming class org.sonar.server.newcodeperiod.ws.SetAction
19:28:19.502 [main] DEBUG com.github.mc1arke.sonarqube.plugin.CommunityBranchAgent -- Transforming class org.sonar.server.newcodeperiod.ws.UnsetAction
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager (file:/C:/sonarqube-10.2.1.78527/lib/sonar-application-10.2.1.78527.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
2023.11.12 19:28:35 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[Web Server] is stopped
2023.11.12 19:28:35 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2023.11.12 19:28:35 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.14.0 does not support any 10.x version though documentation is not clear about it. Looks like there's no working solution for 10.x at the moment.

Here's a link to plugin's issue related to the topic
https://github.com/mc1arke/sonarqube-community-branch-plugin/issues/813